# Accessing a list from different class c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Hi I'm fairly new to c# and have been trying to access my list of cards from another class and get it to display a picture  on form but all i really need is the way to instantiate or reference or whatever the list from my deck class. How would i go about my list of cards in a different class?

```
namespace aGameOf21
{ 
   //adds deck class to Ideck interface
   public class Deck : IDeck
   {
      //default deck call
      public Deck()
      {
         Reset();
      }
      // creates list from the card class with get and set accessors
      public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }
      //resets the decks to unshuffled values default when calling class
      public void Reset()
      {
         // using a LINQ statement takes each enumerable from cards list and combines them
         Cards = Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
                           .SelectMany(s => Enumerable.Range(1, 13)
                           .Select(c => new Card()
                           {
                              Suit = (Suit)s,
                              CardNumber = (CardNumber)c
                           }))
                           .ToList();
        /* foreach(Card c in Cards)
         {   
            Console.WriteLine("Number = {0}, Suit = {1}", c.CardNumber , c.Suit);
         }*/
      }

      public void Shuffle()
      { 
         Cards = Cards.OrderBy(c => Guid.NewGuid())
                      .ToList();
      }

      public ICard TakeCard()
      {
         var card = Cards.FirstOrDefault();
         Cards.Remove(card);
         return card;
      }

      public IEnumerable<ICard> TakeCards(int numberOfCards)
      {
         var cards = Cards.Take(numberOfCards);
         var takeCards = cards as Card[] ?? cards.ToArray();
         Cards.RemoveAll(takeCards.Contains);
         return takeCards;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please ask a question as well.

Comment: add a variable and pass in the list via the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite clear what you're asking, but if you create your deck using:

```
var deck = new Deck();
```

the you can access your list of cards as:

```
var cardList = deck.Cards;
```

You can then pass this list wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment about adding a variable and passing int he list via the constructor.

```
//adds deck class to Ideck interface
   public class Deck : IDeck
   {
      private List _list;
      //default deck call
      public Deck(List list)
      {
         _list = list;
         Reset();
      }
   }
```